# powerpivot 2016 - Divide summed value column with grouped raw value

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I’ve got about 1 million records to perform the following calculation, which I was not very successful so far. I appreciate if you could point me to the right direction.

What I’m trying to do is write measures or calculated fields to:

divide the summed field from a value in the grouped raw.

- Get the quotient
- Get the mod
- Calculate price
- Display the grand total at the bottom

Example file: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkN0kHWepnYzgSujfvGKA15fEygW

[image: Additional calculated fields]

Appreciate your help